# How to compare the scores/scales of SUS and SUMI

Tags: usability, comparison, sus

I have two products that have been evaluated with two different methods. Product A's usability was evaluated with SUMI and Product B's usability was evaluated with SUS. How do I now compare the usability of both products? How do I scientificly conclude that one product's usability is better than the other one, since both methods have different scales?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I scientificly conclude that one product's usability is better than the other one, since both methods have different scales?

You run the study again, this time using the same methodology for both products.

You can probably get an estimate by normalizing the scales, but note that SUMI has a mean of 50%, SUS one of 62% (Lewis and Sauro 2009) to 70% (Bangor et al. 2008). So whatever comparison you get out of these estimates won't really be scientific - or meaningful.